# Are there any open source libraries for Adaptive noise cancellation?

Tags: noise, adaptive-filters, reference-implementation, noise-cancellation

I'm creating a chat application where people can input text via speech and I need to implement noise cancellation using Adaptive noise cancellation technique. I'm using dual microphones for this purpose. 
Is there any open source library available to implement adaptive noise cancellation? or any hardware solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on chat application (presumably web), then I suggest to take a look at [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/). It offers a noise suppressor that works ok for speech.

Another option would be to use part of the [Speex](https://www.speex.org/), which also has a noise suppression module.